# Pass workspace of pipeline multibranch project to downstream freestyle project

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

My setup is as follows:

I have a top-level multibranch pipeline project that builds the various branches of my git project. In addition, I have a single freestyle project that is required for analysis of the individual multibranch pipeline projects. It is a freestyle project, since it requires functionality from plugins that have not yet been updated to include pipeline support.

Since each individual multibranch pipeline project uses a separate workspace, I need the information about the upstream workspace in the freestyle project. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Jenkins [Copy Artifact plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) in your downstream freestyle project, combined with a String parameter do define which job you should copy artifacts from.

**Upstream job** :

```
build job: downstreamJob, parameters: [
      [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'jobName', value: "${env.JOB_NAME}"]
]
```

**Downstream job** :

1. Add a String parameter `jobName`
2. In the `Copy Artifact plugin`, just put `${jobName}` in the `Project name` section

Comment: Overall. it is still not the ideal setup, but that should be fixed once my analysis stuff can be done from a Pipeline job. Other than that, your solution works fine. Thanks! :)

Comment: Abolutely, you can always convert your freestyle job to a pipeline once your plugins become available. I think you already know about the [plugins compatibility](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/COMPATIBILITY.md) page...